# How to transfer table row into another table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables that contain rows. And I have a javascript function that is supposed to move a table row into the second table. So far, my row addition is being performed with Jquery method `closest("tr")`. And it seems to work only when each of the tables has at least one row. And when any of tables is empty, it's not working.

Code, that makes rows move.

```
$(arg).closest("tr").remove()
html=$(arg).closest("tr")

 if(value){
         complete = true;
         $('.completed-tasks').last().after(html)
       }
       else{
         complete = false;
          $('.incompleted-tasks').first().after(html)
        }
```

Here's the structure of the first table.

```
  <h3>Completed</h3>
    <table class='table'>

     <% @tasks.complete.each do |task| %>
      <tr class='completed-tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

        <td>
         .
         .
         .
        </td>

     </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>
```

The second table:

```
<h3>Incompleted</h3>
  <table class='table'>

   <% @tasks.incomplete.each do |task| %>
    <tr class='incompleted-tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

     <td>
      .
      .
      .
     </td>

    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work if the target table is empty is that you're targeting rows with statements like:

```
$('.completed-tasks').last().after(html)
```

If there are none, you're calling `after` on an empty set and there's nowhere to put the content.

Instead, target the table:

```
$(".table").append(html);
```

or ideally, in your markup, add a `tbody` in the table, and target that:

```
$(".table tbody").append(html);
```

---

Side note: I wouldn't call the variable containing a jQuery object with a `tr` element in it `html`, it's misleading. It's not HTML, it's an object. :-)

Comment: Ok, but how do I distinguish both tables? Can I type in a class inside a tbody?

Comment: @BillyLogan: Sure, or a separate class on each table and then a selector like the above.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you are first removing the row from the first table and only then copy it to other table. You should instead

```
html=$(arg).closest("tr")
$(arg).closest("tr").remove()
```

Comment: It didn't change anything